# ASP.NET iFrame Response.Redirect Parent Window

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe

Is it possible to perform a response.redirect within an iFrame to redirect the whole page so that the destination page is viewable full screen and not contained within the iFrame?

Below is the current code behind

```
public partial class ServerResult : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

No.

`Response.Redirect` is a server command which sends (302 ?) header tells the client to redirect.

you are in the iframe world. you can't tell the server:  "Hey , when you send me data - send it to the parent Iframe"

**BUT** What you can do , is this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), 
       "aaa", "window.parent.location = 'http://yoursite.com'", true);
}
```

but you have to remove response.redirect from server.

Edit

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
            if (page != null) page.ClientScript .RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(string), "Redirect", "window.parent.location='" + url + "';", true);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that, but got a validation error saying `Cannot access non-static method 'RegisterClientScriptBlock' in static context`.

Comment: so pass a parameter to the method `public static void RegisterSomeScript(Page page)
    {
         page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript("Load", 
        "<script>.........</script>");
    }`

Comment: Apologies, but now I am getting `Cannot resolve method 'RegisterClientScriptBlock(string, string)'` am I missing something?

Comment: I've also tried `var cm = Page.ClientScript; cm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Redirect", "window.parent.location='" + url + "';", true);` the code does validate, but doesn't fire.